# print single byte after typecasting to char

Tags: c, casting, char, unsigned-char

I am receiving some data from a socket.
After that, I want to print a single byte in the received char array.

Below is the code that I used:

```
char buf[100];                                                                
int i = 0;                                                                    
while (1)                                                                     
{                                                                             
    rc = recv(socket_fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);                                  

    if (rc > 0)                                                                 
    {                                                                           
        printf("Pos1 = %x.\n", (char)buf[17]);   
        printf("Pos2 = %x.\n", (char)buf[22]);   
    }     
}
```

But this prints out 4 bytes. If I typecast the characters to **unsigned char**, then single byte is printed. So what is the difference between these two typecasts, that is resulting in different number of bytes being printed.

**Output:**

```
Pos1 = 1

Pos2 = ffffff83
```

Comment: Why are you using `%x` ? Do you need the hexadecimal value ?

Comment: Yes. I want the value to be printed in hex.

Comment: Share your output. How did you determine that it is printing 4 bytes?

Comment: `%x` is for `unsigned int`. passing negative char causes undefined behaviour

Comment: How do you know `rc > 22`, so `buf[22]` has valid data? You only test if there is at least 1 `char` read.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print just 2 nibbles, use:

```
printf("Pos1 = %02x.\n", (unsigned)(unsigned char)buf[17]);
/*              ^^                           */
/* Print 2 nibbles with 0 prefix if required */
```

On some systems, `char` may behave as `signed char` and you would see `ff` prepended to show negative numbers. So you must cast your `buf[i]` to `unsigned char` on such systems. Second unsigned is used to match the type of argument with specifier `%x`

[Working example](http://ideone.com/NowT1h)

Comment: I have tried that, but the results are same. It is also printing 4 bytes.

Comment: Sorry I copied casting blindly. Make sure you cast to `unsigned char`.

Comment: Yes. It is being prepended with ffffff. My output is like Pos2 = ffffff83.

Comment: Try `printf("Pos1 = %02x.\n", (unsigned)(unsigned char)buf[22]);`

Comment: Or, shorter; `buf[22] & 255U`

Comment: @JohnHascall This is a lot better :)

Answer (score 1):

IF you go to a reference on the C stdio lib for printf

Specifier 'x' prints an Unsigned hexadecimal integer.

So first of all, the print function is going to expect an integer value.

In your example you are casting to a signed char.

What appears to be going on, is when you cast your variable to a signed char, and if that value exceeds 127 (0X7F), the signed bit which is set, will be extended to a 4-Byte integer entity.  On the otherhand, if the value is positive (0 to 127), the output (though technically an unsigned int value) will be the same as the unsigned char cast.

For example 128 (0x80) will appear as FFFFFF80 if you cast as a Char
and 80 when cast as an unsigned char.

127 on the otherhand will be displayed as 7F with either cast.

Therefore, when using printf the variable type you want to print should match the specifier type.

Answer (score 1):

> So what is the difference between these two typecasts, that is resulting in different number of bytes?

Each input argument passed to function `printf` is "extended" to 4 or 8 bytes (depending on its type) before being pushed into the stack.

When you pass an input argument whose type is `signed`, the sign-bit is "preserved".

For example, `signed char 0x89` is extended to `signed int 0xFFFFFF89`.

While `unsigned char 0x89` is extended to `unsigned int 0x00000089`.

---

Please note that the answer above is platform-dependent.

I've assumed that on your platform:

- `CHAR_BIT` is 8
- `sizeof int` is 4
- `sizeof double` is 8

AFAIK with regards to `printf` input arguments:

- An integral argument smaller than `int` is extended to `int`
- A non-integral argument smaller than `double` is extended to `double`

Answer (score 0):

Tell `printf` that you are passing in half of the half of an `unsigned int` by doing

```
printf("Pos1 = %hhx.\n", (unsigned char) buf[17]);
```